# .sitx file — 7-Zip can't open it. What can?

Tags: file-management, archiving

I have a .sitx archive. I think this is an old Mac compressed archive format, but I need to open it in Windows.

7-Zip doesn't recognize it.

What should I use?

Comment: Look out for that ATM!

Comment: What ATM are you talking about?

Comment: I wish there was a better answer to this. Aladdin haven't updated StuffIt deluxe since 2010 and Stuffit Expander for Windows hasn't been updated for 5 years. I can't get it to work under Windows 10. It's a real shame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was created by Stuffit, there is a free expander program to extract it.

http://stuffit-expander.en.softonic.com/mac

Answer (score 1):

For linux users:

```
sudo apt-get install unar
unar Archive.sitx
```

Comment: @micsthepick - If was applicable to the author since they accepted the answer.  They must have had a Mac.

Comment: @micsthepick - They didn’t have to actually accept any answer.