# Opening a SITX file on Windows 10

Tags: windows, archiving, file-format

This question bears some similarity to [.sitx File --- 7zip can't open it, what can?](https://superuser.com/questions/169956/sitx-file-7zip-cant-open-it-what-can) - however, that was answered six years ago and I don't know if the response is still accurate in 2016.

SITX is a proprietary archive format created by Smith Micro software. In the early 2010s they released StuffIt Deluxe for Windows and in 2011 they released an updated version of their free StuffIt Expander tool - neither work in Windows 10, however, and they were poorly-written when they were new.

Three years ago I asked Smith Micro if they planned on releasing a build of StuffIt Deluxe for modern PCs and they said it was imminent; I have heard nothing since then. Since the SITX file format is now basically abandonware, I wonder if there are any other programs that claim compatibility with the format - I was unable to find anything.

Partial note goes to [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html), which claims partial .SITX support; it was unable to open my files, however. I have roughly 10GB of files in various .SITX archives so extracting everything in a virtual machine will take a very long time. Is there not any better, native option?

Comment: Windows 10 supports booting to a virtual machine, there is some skill level involved, but fully possible.  By doing so you then you are running what is initially a bare metal virtual machine.

Comment: Though if you're running sitx, the best option would be to get a *classic mac* VM with OS 9.x, extract, and exfiltrate the data somehow. This might get *messy* quick.

Comment: SITX was the new version of SIT, Journeyman Geek. I don't think a classic Mac VM in SheepShaver is going to be able to cut it, and even if it could, I don't want to try leaving it with 10GB of data to extract - I'd be there for weeks.

Comment: Might be simpler to give the files to someone with a Mac & let them send you the result back. Expander still works on El Capitan, I had to re-download & use it just recently to extract something that was being stubborn.

Comment: why do you think doing things inside a VM will be a lot slower? Just share the host folders and access them directly from the guest